# How to add new tags to JTidy?

Tags: html, parsing, jtidy

I am trying to use jTidy for extract data from (real world)HTML.But jTidy doesnt parse custom tags.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <myCustomTag>some text</myCustomTag>
    <anotherCustom>more text</anotherCustom>
  </body>
</html>
```

I cant get texts between custom tags.I have to use jTidy because i ll use xpath.

I tried HTMLCleaner but it doesnt support full xpath functions.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374232/jtidy-pretty-print-custom-html-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set the properties using a Java Properties object, for example:

```
import java.util.Properties;
Properties oProps = new Properties();
oProps.setProperty("new-blocklevel-tags", "header hgroup article footer nav");

Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setConfigurationFromProps(oProps);
```

This should save you having to create and load a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#new-blocklevel-tags

The quick and dirty of it is to create a file, I named mine jTidyTags and call:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setConfigurationFromFile("jTidyTags");
```

After that it will throw up a warning saying it isn't W3C compliant but who cares. That will let you parse the file.

An example of jTidyTags for you would be:

```
new-blocklevel-tags: myCustomTag anotherCustom
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Ethan, thx for answer.It was the first thing that i tried is "new-blocklevel-tags", but it doesn't working.

Comment: Have you tried adding the other "new-" tags? I don't have my code in front of me at the moment. I will look at it when I get to work.

Comment: Here is the exact line that I am using in my code:
    new-blocklevel-tags: barcode box line