# jTidy pretty print custom HTML tag

Tags: java, angularjs, jtidy

I'm trying to use JTidy to pretty print a well formed HTML generated by the user:

```
<div class="component-holder ng-binding ng-scope ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-component="cronos-datasource" id="cronos-datasource-817277">
    <datasource name="" entity="" key="" endpoint="" rows-per-page="">
        <i class="cpn cpn-datasource"></i>
    </datasource>
</div>
```

This is my config:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setIndentContent(true);
tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
tidy.setTidyMark(false);
tidy.setWraplen(2000);
tidy.setDropProprietaryAttributes(false);
tidy.setDropEmptyParas(false);
tidy.setTrimEmptyElements(false);
```

But jTidy is removing my AngularJS `datasource` directive. Is there a way to workarround this issue?

I'm getting this from the log:

```
line 1 column 191 - Error: <datasource> is not recognized!
line 1 column 191 - Warning: discarding unexpected <datasource>
```

Removing `tidy.setXHTML(true)` or setting it to false and adding `tidy.setXmlTags(true)` actually solve this issue and it start to consider user defined tags, but this is not a good solution because JTidy starts trying to close self enclosing tags.

```
 <!-- this code -->
 <img src="anythig.jpg"/>
 <div id="anyid"></div> 

 <!-- will become -->
 <img src="anythig.jpg">
     <div id="anyid"></div>
 </img>
```

I need a formatter for a text editor. I can't assure what directives our users will define and use. It must be a generic solution which works for any user defined directive

Comment: What version of JTidy are you using? Are you sure there is no other configuration? AFAIK `setXmlTags(true)` should solve this.

Comment: `setXmlTags(true)` actually solves this, but it starts trying to close self enclosing tags example <img></img>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by make some changes in JTidy source

https://github.com/nanndoj/jtidy

I have added a new configuration called `dropProprietaryTags`

```
tidy.setDropProprietaryTags(false);
```

Now it's working fine for me. It's set to `true` by default so JTidy can work in the old way if the new property is not set to `false`

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the following property after your current configuration:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("new-blocklevel-tags", "datasource");
tidy.getConfiguration().addProps(props);
```

See http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#new-blocklevel-tags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @manouti, but i'm writing a pretty formatter for a text editor. I can't assure what directives our users will define and use. It must be a generic solution